# How to inject ANY information about test in spring testing?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, junit4, spring-test

I would like some of my beans know something about test. SOMETHING. May be test class name or some of it's methods.

For example, suppose my test class has a method

```
public String getTestName() {
   return getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

This method returns test name and can be overridden.

Is it possible to inject this name into some beans of Spring context, to use during test?

For example, with autowire feature:

```
@Autowired
public String testName;
```

not only in test class, but in other beans too.

**UPDATE**

Below are two (failed) attempts to implement injecting `testInstance`. May be there are some convenient ways to do that?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestClassAwareTry._Config.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(value = { TestClassAwareTry._Listener.class },
   mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)

public class TestClassAwareTry {

   /**
    * Interface to tag beans, who want to know if they are in test
    */
   public interface TestInstanceAware {
      void setTestInstance(Object value);
   }

   /**
    * Sample bean, which would like to know if it is in test
    */
   public static class MyBean implements TestInstanceAware {

      private Object testInstance;

      {
         System.out.println("MyBean constructed");
      }

      public void setTestInstance(Object value) {
         this.testInstance = value;
         System.out.println("testInstance set");
      }

      public Object getTestInstance() {
         return testInstance;
      }
   }

   /**
    * Attempt to inject testInstance with a bean, implementing {@link BeanPostProcessor}
    */
   public static class TestInstanceInjector implements BeanPostProcessor {


      public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         if( bean instanceof TestInstanceAware ) {
            TestInstanceAware aware = (TestInstanceAware) bean;

            // we don't have access to test instance here
            // otherwise I would write
            //Object testInstance = getTestInstance();
            //aware.setTestInstance(testInstance);
         }
         return bean;
      }

      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         return bean;
      }
   }

   /**
    * Attempt to inject testInstance with test execution listener
    */
   public static class _Listener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

      @Override
      public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
         Object testInstance = testContext.getTestInstance();
         ApplicationContext context = testContext.getApplicationContext();

         // we don't have setBean() method
         // I would write if I have
         // context.setBean("testInstance", context);

      }

   }

   /**
    * Java-based configuration
    */
   @Configuration
   public class _Config {

      @Bean
      public MyBean myBean() {
         return new MyBean();
      }

      @Bean
      public TestInstanceInjector testInstanceInjector() {
         return new TestInstanceInjector();
         // I would acquire test instance here and pass it to constructor, if I can
      }

   }

   @Autowired
   public MyBean myBean;

   @Test
   public void testInjected() {
      assertSame( this, myBean.getTestInstance());
   }
}
```

Comment: for the second part: look at Spring's Integration Test support: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

Comment: Looking for a long time, but can't find. Just question matured :)

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I need my beans write some information into test-specific directory when testing. So, I need to setup my beans with some information, depending on test.

Comment: Do they only write this data during test, or do they write this data even in live?

Comment: @mlk they just write data into configured place and I want to configure them to write into temporary testable place to test what they write

Comment: Does my solution below answer your question or have I missed something?

Comment: @Dims, it's been a while, but curious if you eventually solve it? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up creating ContextCustomizerFactory that registers BeanPostProcessor

```
package com.company.testing.base.spring;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfigurationAttributes;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizer;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory;

public class TestAwareContextCustomizerFactory implements ContextCustomizerFactory {

  @Override
  public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(
      Class<?> testClass, List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> configAttributes) {
    return (context, mergedConfig) -> {
      ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();
      beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(
          new TestInstanceAwareBeanPostProcessor(mergedConfig.getTestClass()));
    };
  }
}
```

TestInstanceAwareBeanPostProcessor

```
public class TestInstanceAwareBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

  private final Class<?> testClass;

  TestInstanceAwareBeanPostProcessor(Class<?> testClass) {
    this.testClass = testClass;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
      throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof TestClassAware) {
      ((TestClassAware) bean).setTestClass(testClass);
    }
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
  }
}
```

resources/META-INF/spring.factories

```
# ContextCustomizerFactories for the Spring TestContext Framework
org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory = \
  com.company.testing.base.spring.TestAwareContextCustomizerFactory
```

Comment: This approach looks interesting, but there are a couple of missing pieces. Could you share an example of the `TestClassAware` class as well as how one would go about consuming the `TestAwareContextCustomizerFactory` class to inject test information?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to do this is by delaying creation of the subject until you are in the test method and to have the bean in the prototype scope.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { LiveConfig.class, DevConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("Dev")
public class MeTest {
    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    DevConfig devConfig;

    @Rule
    public TestName nameRule = new TestName();

    @Before
    public void setName() {
        devConfig.setSettings(nameRule.getMethodName());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bean subject = context.getBean(Bean.class);
        System.out.println(subject.settings);
        assertThat(subject.settings, is(nameRule.getMethodName()));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Bean subject = context.getBean(Bean.class);
        System.out.println(subject.settings);
        assertThat(subject.settings, is(nameRule.getMethodName()));
    }
}

@Configuration
class LiveConfig {
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    public String getSettings() {
        return "/some/real/file.txt";
    }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Bean getBean() {
        return new Bean();
    }
}

@Configuration
class DevConfig {
    private String settings;

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    @Profile("Dev")
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public String getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    public void setSettings(String settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}

class Bean {
    public Bean() {
        System.out.println("Bean");
    }


    String settings;
    @Autowired
    void setSettings(String settings) {
        System.out.println("Settings: " + settings);
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

This uses [Profile](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)s to change what Live sees and what the tests see, and the a [NameRule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestName.html) to get the name. It is clunky.

I would NOT use the TestName rule, but rather the [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule and use that to set whatever setting your application uses for the output folder. I'd also only use DI in a test in very rare cases (i.e. full blown integration tests).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void testName() {
    MyBean b = new MyBean(MyTest.class.getSimpleName());
    b.doSomething();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a more elegant way using Spring Boot *Auto configuration* feature by making yours, this way:

1. define a `Configuration` class that exposes or registers your bean this way:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class MyBeanProviderConfiguration {
      @ConditionalOnMissingBean
      @Bean
      public MyBean myBean() {
         // return a fully initialised MyBean instance
      }
   }
   ```
2. Then define a custom annotation *Spring Boot like*, say `@AutoConfigureMyBean` this way:

   ```
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
   @Target(ElementType.TYPE) 
   @ImportAutoConfiguration(MyBeanProviderConfiguration.class) 
   public @interface AutoConfigureMyBean {}
   ```
3. Then you can use this in your *Spring test*, here is an example:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @AutoConfigureMyBean
   public class MyTest {
      @Autowired
      MyBean myBean;
   }
   ```

Or also declare your *MyBean* `@Autowired` dependent bean in a regular Spring test (using a Config class), A `MyBean` instance will be automatically injected into it.